# Windows Phone 8 - RichTextBoxes

Tags: c#, xaml

Text formatting Disappears when inserting text into RichTextBox. Is there any way to get around this problem?

I have some text in a RichTextBox which I inserted from XAML when i created the RichTextBox. Then I created some buttons to format those text but I still want to insert more text after formatting those text but the problem is when I inserting more text in to the RichTextBox my earlier formats Disappears from the previous text. Sorry for misspelling those words. Is there any way to get around this problem.

```xml
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              Background="White" Cursor="Wait" Margin="14,10,12,0" Height="179"
              VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <RichTextBox:C1RichTextBox x:Name="writingArea" Phone:C1NagScreen.Nag="True"
                               IsReadOnly="True" Text="yes yes"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

```
private void bButton_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    FontWeight? fw = writingArea.Selection.FontWeight;
    writingArea.Selection.FontWeight = fw.HasValue && fw.Value == FontWeights.Bold
    ? FontWeights.Normal
    : FontWeights.Bold;  

    //writingArea.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi This is in \b bold\b0.}";
}

private void aButton_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    this.createArray('a');
}

private void cButton_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    this.createArray('c');
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I might suggest re-formatting your question as it's not obviously clear what you're asking. Especially if one were to interpret it by the dictionary definition of "despairer" and I don't think you mean to say that your text formatting is depressed. :)

Comment: I have some text in a RichTextBox which I inserted from XAML when i created the RichTextBox. Then I created some buttons to format those text but I still want to insert more text after formatting those text but the problem is when I inserting more text in to the RichTextBox my earlier formats Disappears from the previous text. Sorry for misspelling those words. Is there any way to get around this problem.

Comment: @TheJaya Hello, you should add this text to your original post. By the way, add the code your tried.

Comment: I added the code I tried.